# Passing a row type to jsonb_to_recordset syntax errors

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to work out how to expand a JSONB field with a `jsonb_to_recordset` and a custom type.

Postgres 11.4.

This is just a test case, but for the minute I'm trying to work out the syntax. I've got a table named `data_file_info` with a JSONB field named `table_stats`. The JSONB field always includes a JSON array with the same structure:

```
[
    {"table_name":"Activity","record_count":0,"table_number":214},
    {"table_name":"Assembly","record_count":1,"table_number":15},
    {"table_name":"AssemblyProds","record_count":0,"table_number":154}
]
```

The following code works correctly:

```
  from data_file_info,
       jsonb_to_recordset(table_stats) as table_stats_splat (
            table_name text, 
            record_count integer,
            table_number integer
        )
```

What I would like to do is pass in a custm type definition instead of the long-form  column definition list shown above. Here's the matching type:

```
create type data.table_stats_type as (
    table_name text, 
    record_count integer,
    table_number integer)
```

Some examples I've seen, and the docs say, that you *can* supply a type name using a `null:row_type` casting in the first parameter to `jsonb_to_recordset`. The examples that I've found use in-line JSON, while I'm trying to pull stored JSON. I've made a few attempts, all have failed. Below are two of the trials, with errors. Can someone point me towards the correct syntax?

**FAIL**:

```
select table_stats_splat.*

   from data_file_info,
        jsonb_populate_recordset(null::table_stats_type, data_file_info) as table_stats_splat;

-- ERROR:  function jsonb_populate_recordset(table_stats_type, data_file_info) does not exist

-- LINE 4:         jsonb_populate_recordset(null::table_stats_type, dat...
            ^

-- HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. (Line 4)
```

**FAIL**:

```
select *
  from jsonb_populate_recordset(NULL::table_stats_type, (select table_stats from data_file_info)) as table_stats_splat;

 -- ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression. (Line 2)
```

I'm doubtlessly missing something pretty obvious, and am hoping someone can suggest what that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the column as the second parameter:

```
select table_stats_splat.*
from data_file_info,
    jsonb_populate_recordset(null::table_stats_type, table_stats) as table_stats_splat;
```

Comment: It's the little things ;-) Thanks for spotting my silly mistake.